# Ruby Rails: Upload File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-file-uploading.htm). It has written in previous version of Rails and I am using Rails 4. I am trying to upload file but I am getting following error:

```
NoMethodError in UploadController#uploadfile
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #3):

class DataFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.save(upload)
    name =  upload['datafile'].original_filename
    directory = "public/data"
    # create the file path
    path = File.join(directory, name)

Rails.root: C:/Ruby193/mylibrary

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/data_file.rb:3:in `save'
app/controllers/upload_controller.rb:6:in `uploadfile'
```

Here is data_file.rb

```
class DataFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.save(upload)
    name =  upload['datafile'].original_filename
    directory = "public/data"
    # create the file path
    path = File.join(directory, name)
    # write the file
    File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(upload['datafile'].read) }
  end
end
```

Here is controller upload_controller.rb

```
class UploadController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :file => 'app\views\upload\uploadfile.html'
  end
  def uploadfile
    post = DataFile.save(params[:upload])
    render :text => "File has been uploaded successfully"
  end
end
```

Here is uploadfile.html

```
<h1>File Upload</h1>
<%= form_tag({:action => 'uploadfile'}, :multipart => true) do %>
<p><label for="upload_file">Select File</label>
    <%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile' %></p>
<%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
<% end %>
```

What should I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldnt this form be a multipart form?

Comment: It's a multipart form in the tutorial, and you can't upload files without a multipart form, so yeah. I should be multipart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like params[:upload] isn't what you think it is. You forgot to set the form to be multipart. If fixing that doesn't make it work, start inspecting params to see what you're actually getting.

```
def uploadfile
  puts params.inspect # Add this line to see what's going on
  post = DataFile.save(params[:upload])
  render :text => "File has been uploaded successfully"
end
```

Also, it's not a great "answer," but I've had good success using [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to handle file uploads. If you just want something that works (rather than learning how to do it yourself), check into that.